# Questions about Label and Cross Reference

Tags: cross-referencing

I am trying to use cross reference in an article, here is a sample of my code.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}   % set the margins to 1in on all sides
\usepackage{graphicx}              % to include figures
\usepackage{amsmath}               % great math stuff
\usepackage{amsfonts}              % for blackboard bold, etc
\usepackage{amsthm}                % better theorem environments
\usepackage{epsfig}         % For postscript
\usepackage{epic,eepic}       % For epic and eepic output from xfig
\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{pdfsync}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{lmodern}






\newtheoremstyle{break}% name
  {}%         Space above, empty = `usual value'
  {}%         Space below
  {\itshape}% Body font
  {}%         Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}% Thm head font
  {.}%        Punctuation after thm head
  {\newline}% Space after thm head: \newline = linebreak
  {}%         Thm head spec

\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{quest}[thm]{Question}

\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{defns}[thm]{Definitions}
\newtheorem{con}[thm]{Construction}
\newtheorem{exmp}[thm]{Example}
\newtheorem{exmps}[thm]{Examples}
\newtheorem{notn}[thm]{Notation}
\newtheorem{notns}[thm]{Notations}
\newtheorem{addm}[thm]{Addendum}
\newtheorem{exer}[thm]{Exercise}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rk}[thm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{rks}[thm]{Remarks}
\newtheorem{warn}[thm]{Warning}
\newtheorem{sch}[thm]{Scholium}

\newenvironment{sketchpf}{\noindent{\it Sketch of Proof}\hspace*{1em}}{\qed\bigskip\\}
\newenvironment{proof-idea}{\noindent{\bf Proof Idea}\hspace*{1em}}{\qed\bigskip\\}
\newenvironment{proof-of-lemma}[1]{\noindent{\bf Proof of Lemma #1}\hspace*{1em}}{\qed\bigskip\\}
\newenvironment{proof-attempt}{\noindent{\bf Proof Attempt}\hspace*{1em}}{\qed\bigskip\\}
\newenvironment{proofof}[1]{\noindent{\bf Proof} of #1:\hspace*{1em}}{\qed\bigskip\\}
\newenvironment{remark}{\noindent{\bf Remark}\hspace*{1em}}{\bigskip}

\begin{document}
\begin{prop}\label{2}
   This is just an sample.
\end{prop}
By Proposition \ref{2}, we can see the problem.
\end{document}
```

But when I compile my file, there is a "1" in a square box besides Proposition (the number of above proposition), and at the reference part, there is a small "1" in a square box lying above Proposition.

Is there a way to get rid of these square boxes?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: it's best not to use numbers as labels (it works but it is very confusing when the label number is different to the printed proposition number) do you have `showkeys` or `showlabels` package loaded?

Comment: OK, Christian. I edited my question. But how to post codes in the format of Latex here? My codes are too messy.

Comment: @FangyangTian I fixed it; just select the code part and click on the `{}` button above the editor window (or hit Control-K). Avoid loading `epsfig` preferring `graphicx`; also `pdfsync` should *never* be loaded.

Comment: don't use `epsfig` (it is only needed to help port old (pre 1994) latex2.09 documents to latex2e.

Comment: I deleted epsfig, and pdfsync, but these boxes are still there .......

Comment: @FangyangTian they are unreleated: you need to delete `showkeys`

Answer (score 5):

As I guessed in comment, you have

```
\usepackage{showkeys}
```

which is a package for drafts only, to show the internal label.

Comment: Sorry, David, it doesn't work......

Comment: @FangyangTian what doesn't work?

Comment: I put a picture of the output pdf. I think my problem is clearer now.

Comment: @FangyangTian it was clear before, you just need to remove `showkeys`

Comment: @FangyangTian -- if you comment out `showkeys`, the boxes (and the report of the labels) disappears.  also, if you are using `amsart`, you don't need to include the packages `amsmath`, `amsthm`, and `amsfonts` -- those are already either preloaded or incorporated in the document class.

Comment: Thank you guys. Now I understand what you mean, Thank you so much.

Comment: Whatever else you do, don't load the `pdfsync` package. For one, it's not needed if you use a version of pdfLaTeX/XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX that's more recent than ca 2008. And, as the package's user guide warns, "pdfsync uses extremely sensible code. You should not use `pdfsync` on final documents because it can change the layout rather significantly (different page/line breaks are the most obvious changes) ..."